# How to mock context for jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm fairly new to jest testing and was wondering how to mock my context provider as my current setup returns undefined in the component. I'm not sure how to mock the withUserDetails function within jest, which I suspect is the problem. I've had success in the past using a form provider in jest, but it wasn't wrapped with a function and I was able to just pass the context in like this test case.

Modal Component

```
   <UserContext.Consumer>
    {(data) => (
        <Box
        sx={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderTop: '1px solid rgb(241,241,242)',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            marginTop: '1.125rem',
            minHeight: '4rem',
            padding: '1.5rem 1rem .75rem',
        }}
        >
        {console.log('user', data)}
        <Button
            aria-label="Cancel confirm request"
            onClick={handleClose}
            sx={{ borderRadius: '0', padding: '0 .5rem' }}
            data-testid={'cancelBtn'}
        >
            Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button
            className="search"
            variant="contained"
            aria-label="Send Request"
            onClick={handleSubmit(sendFinalPayload(data))}
            data-testid={'sendRequestBtn'}
        >
            Send Request
        </Button>
        </Box>
    )}
    </UserContext.Consumer>
           
    
    export default withUserDetails(ConfirmModal);
```

Context

```
export const withUserDetails = (Component) => {
  const UserComponent = (props) => {
    const { data } = fetchUser();

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={data}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  };

  return UserComponent;
};
```

Test

```
import React from 'react';
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from 'test-utils';
import Modal from '~/components/modal/confirm.js';
import { UserContext } from '~/shared/contexts/index';

const setupModalConfirm = (props = { context: {} }) => {
    const { context, ...overrides } = props;
    const handleClose = jest.fn();
    const defaultPropsConfirm = {
        open: true,
        handleClose
    };

    const userContext = {
        user: {
            displayName: "User",
            userId: "UserId",
            permissions: {
                isAuthenticated: true,
            }
        }
    }

    const utils = render(
         <UserContext.Provider value={{ ...userContext, ...context }}>
            <Modal {...defaultPropsConfirm} {...overrides} />
         </UserContext.Provider>
    );

    const instance = utils.baseElement;
    return {
        ...utils,
        instance,
        handleClose
    };
};

it('renders correctly and opens modal',  () => {
    const { instance } = setupModalConfirm();
    expect(instance).toMatchSnapshot(); 
});
it('closes the modal', () => {
    const { handleClose } = setupModalConfirm(); 
    const button = screen.getByTestId('cancelBtn');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(handleClose).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
it('can call confirm', async () => {
    setupModalConfirm(); 
    const button = screen.getByTestId('sendRequestBtn');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(button).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is to mock as little as possible and have the mocks as simple as possible.

In this case, I'd recommend mocking the `fetchUser` rather than `withUserDetails`, as it's `fetchUser` that's reaching out to the "outside world". Also, you'll be leaving more surface area for the tests to cover (i.e the entire logic of the `withUserDetails`) which is good.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```js
// Create a mock implementation for fetchUser
const mockFetchUser = jest.fn(() => ({ 
  data: {
    displayName: "User",
    userId: "UserId",
    permissions: { isAuthenticated: true }
  } 
}));

// Provide the mock implementation for fetchUser
jest.mock('./path/to/fetchUser', () => ({
  fetchUser: mockFetchUser,
}));

// ... Rest of the tests
```